# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression on vb/access

Tags: vb.net, operator-keyword

I've been looking for an answer but I can't understand them since I'm noob on visual basic (I haven't been taught how to use it in school, I just search on the net to learn).

Here is my problem: `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'pinN='.`

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =   C:\Users\Billy Otsuka\Desktop\VB Fiiles\Prototype-Prototype\Sample.accdb")
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table3] WHERE pinN= " & TextBox1.Text & "", con)
con.Open()
Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If (sdr.Read() = True) Then
    adminLogin.Show()
    Me.Hide()
Else
    MsgBox("Invalid pin")
End If
```

The highlighted word is `sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()`

In this code I want to enter a 4 number pin and if its correct I can go to the next form but if its wrong it will not.  I'm using an access database.

I really appreciate if anyone can tell me what's wrong since i don't have any idea what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM
 [Table3] WHERE pinN= '"  & TextBox1.Text & "'", con)
```

You don't have the singles quotes on your select

**EDIT**: Try this:

```
 New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table3] WHERE pinN= " & TextBox1.Text, con)
```

Comment: after putting single quotes i got now the error Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: what is the value in Textbo2.text is it a date or plain text?. What value is in it debugging?

Comment: value i put is 1234 since its asking for a pin.

Comment: Trry with this:  New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table3] WHERE pinN= " & TextBox1.Text, con)

Comment: can i ask one more. It works if i put numbers but if i leave it blank it gives me the missing operator error. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You can check if string.isNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.text) and then change your query to SELECT * FROM [TABLE3] without the where clause

Comment: This code is wide open to Sql Injection attack.  Better to use a parameterized query instead.

Answer (score 0):

What is textbox1.text type?

```
If textbox1.text is **numeric** :
   New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table3] WHERE pinN= " & TextBox1 & ""
else
   New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table3] WHERE pinN ='" & TextBox1 & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issue doing the concatenation, I used a parameter to solve this issue.

```
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table3] WHERE pinN= @myPinN", con)
con.Open()  
cmd.Parameters.Add("@myPinN", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "myPinNValue"
```